# Performance problems with an xslt transform using date functions from "http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"

Tags: xslt

We have an xslt transform that uses the functions add, duration and seconds from the EXSLT dates-and-times module.  The performance of this transform has been very slow.

As an experiment, I removed the calls to the functions in the dates-and-time module.  The performance of the transform improved by a factor of almost 100!  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Which implementation of the functions are you using? (the version written as XSLT templates?)

And which functions? And which XSLT processor?

Some of these functions are computationally intensive and involve heavy recursion; template calls may be expensive in some implementations.